# bash split string into array and write to file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want split the string with delimiter comma and write it to a file. I have the below script but when I see the output(temp.txt) I see the complete for loop code written to file..
Can anyone help me to fix this issue

```
#!/bin/bash -e

string1=a/b,b/c,c/d

IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "$string1"

cat << 'EOF' > temp.txt
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
EOF
```

#### Expected file temp.txt output

```
a/b
b/c
c/d
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
string1=a/b,b/c,c/d
IFS=', ' read -ra array <<< "$string1"
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" > temp.txt
```

And the longer way:

```
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$e"
done > temp.txt
```

Another using IFS:

```
IFS=$'\n' eval 'echo "${array[*]}" > temp.txt'
```

Note: Changing the IFS is unnecessary but if you want to strictly split the string with commas, change it to `IFS=,`:

```
IFS=, read -ra array <<< "$string1"
```

Comment: +1; starts out with the best-practices `printf` approach and shows a series of additional correct answers (with the caveat that the `echo` version wouldn't work correctly with `-E` or `-n` as data on account of bash's non-POSIX behavior). Also, this is interesting to me as a demonstration of a place where `eval` is entirely safe and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IFS` is incorrect, there should be no space. Also, you can just indirect the output of the loop to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

string1=a/b,b/c,c/d

IFS=',' read -a array <<< "$string1"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done > temp.txt
```

If your only intention is to turn commas into newlines, you could use something simple like `tr`:

```
tr , '\n' <<<"$string1" > temp.txt
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering what is space doing in all the answers and the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `-d` option of the read builtin command in a loop like this:

```
while read -d, -r; do
    echo "$REPLY"
done <<<"$string1," > temp.txt
```

You'll notice that I added a `,` to the end of the `string1` expansion as `-d` is substituting `,` for a newline character.

Although it requires a bit more code, you could avoid adding the extra comma to the here string by doing another `echo $REPLY` after the loop.

```
{ while read -d, -r; do
      echo "$REPLY"
  done <<<"$string1"
  echo $REPLY
} > temp.txt
```

You could also just use a subshell to `echo` your array with a newline `IFS`:

```
IFS=, read -ra array <<<"$string1"
(IFS=$'\n'; echo -e "${array[*]}") > temp.txt
```

Comment: Without the trailing comma you just have to use `$REPLY` one more time after the loop ends (because read returns non-zero on `EOF`). Though that's likely less useful of a pattern.